# How do I change the selected item label in a Dataverse Form lookup?

Tags: dynamics-crm, powerapps, dataverse, powerapps-modeldriven

In a dataverse table I use autonumber as the primary name column. When I add existing rows (n:n relation) using a subgrid, a search pane is displayed on the right side of the screen. The quicklist shows up correctly, but it doesn't make sense displaying in the list of selected items.

[image]

How/where do I change this?

Comment: from the screenshot I am not able to understand correctly your question. can you rephrase or add more details? like this is the behavior, this is the behavior I wish to have, also a screenshot from the table that contains the autonumber will help

Answer (score 0):

Typically the grid/list/card will show the first three fields of lookup view designed for that entity while searching/associating. You have that luxury to rearrange the fields to display including name, auto number and other fields.

Lookup display field is designed to show the Name field of that entity record by default (only choice). Since you are using auto number type for that Name field, it’s showing only auto number - this is expected.

Normally we will have a separate auto number field and concatenate few fields along with auto number to the Name field to make sense. But you chose the other way.